i was simply running the surver in vite react and got error

conditional-rendering---rendering-lists-in-react@0.0.0 dev
vite

Rendering' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
throw err;

i was simply running the surver in vite react and got error
how to solve this error
